# What are the differences among these 3 system images for Android virtual device?

Tags: android, virtual

As the screenshot, what are the differences among these 3 system images for Android virtual device?
[image: SDK Manager for Android Developer Tools]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One is intel's, one is google's, and one is not a system image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Google APIs** isn't an image
- **Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image** it's a simple Android image, built from AOSP(Android Open Source Project). There is no third party apps or services. Use it to test how your app will work on all android devices.
- **Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image** it's an Android image which has Google GMS services built-in. Use it for apps which require access to Google Maps, Location Services, Payments, [etc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages)

Google provides builds for different CPU architectures: Intel and ARM.

Comment: So, is the "Google APIs" a library which is some like "Google Play Licensing Library"?

Comment: @Johnson kind of. It's a set of libraries which allow you to access to GMS (which is on device) [here is more info](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client)